# Unexpected token : a partir duma URL com extensão .json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Ao tentar obter um JSON através da URL: `http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/gmap/shapes/35/MU_M13_3550308_1000.json`

Recebo um status `200` com o erro:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Utilizando AJAX da seguinte forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/gmap/shapes/35/MU_M13_3550308_1000.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(thrownError);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Qual a causa do erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O conteúdo da [URL fornecida](http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/gmap/shapes/35/MU_M13_3550308_1000.json) não retorna um JSON válido. É por isso que você está tendo esse erro.

Aparentemente, *no caso específico do seu problema*, parece que estão faltando as aspas nas chaves dos itens. O que eu faria seria criar um endpoint em um servidor intermediário que baixasse o arquivo original, tratasse-o e retornasse o arquivo corrigido.